Flutter MobX ObservableList not updating UI when modifying items directly
I'm using MobX in my Flutter app and encountering an issue with updating the UI. I have an ObservableList that I use to render a list of items on the screen. The ObservableList is typed as ObservableList<SelectItem>. When I click on one of the rendered boxes, it should theoretically update the entire widget that is wrapped with an Observer. However, it only updates when I use methods like .remove, .add, .clear, etc...
When I loop through the items and modify them directly, the UI doesn't recognize the changes and nothing happens. Here's an example of my working code:
@action
void selectFuel(int index) {
  for (int i = 0; i < fuelSelectItemList.length; i++) {
    if (i == index &&
        fuelSelectItemList[i].object.avaliable != null &&
        fuelSelectItemList[i].object.avaliable!.compareTo(0) <= 0) {
      ToastService.error('Estoque indisponível no momento');
      return;
    }
  }

  List<SelectItem<Product>> list = fuelSelectItemList.toList();
  fuelSelectItemList.clear();
  fuelOrderItem.fuelTankFraction = null;

  for (var fuelItem in list) {
    fuelItem.selected = false;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    if (i == index) {
      list[i].selected = true;
      fuelOrderItem.product = list[i].object;
      break;
    }
  }
  fuelSelectItemList = ObservableList.of(list);
}

However, I don't want to create a new list and then clear the ObservableList only to reassign it, as I could be modifying the ObservableList directly. Am I missing something, or is this behavior expected?

Additional Context: MobX version: 2.3.3+2 Flutter version: 3.22.2

Is there a way to directly modify the items within the ObservableList and have the changes immediately reflected in the UI without creating and reassigning a new list? Any help or guidance would be appreciated. Thank you!
